# Enumerating replicates in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this example `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(id = rep(letters[1:10],2), sub.id = c(rep("P",10), rep("M",10)), group = rep(c(rep("X", 7), rep("Y", 3)),2), class = rep(c(rep("A1", 5), rep("A2", 5)),2))

> df
   id sub.id group class
1   a      P     X    A1
2   b      P     X    A1
3   c      P     X    A1
4   d      P     X    A1
5   e      P     X    A1
6   f      P     X    A2
7   g      P     X    A2
8   h      P     Y    A2
9   i      P     Y    A2
10  j      P     Y    A2
11  a      M     X    A1
12  b      M     X    A1
13  c      M     X    A1
14  d      M     X    A1
15  e      M     X    A1
16  f      M     X    A2
17  g      M     X    A2
18  h      M     Y    A2
19  i      M     Y    A2
20  j      M     Y    A2
```

`df$id`  appears twice for its corresponding respective `df$sub.id` "P" and `df$sub.id` "M".

I would like to add a column which enumerates the replicates of the different group and class combinations and respects the `df$id` values. The resulting `data.frame` would therefore be:

```
> df
   id sub.id group class replicate
1   a      P     X    A1         1
2   b      P     X    A1         2
3   c      P     X    A1         3
4   d      P     X    A1         4
5   e      P     X    A1         5
6   f      P     X    A2         6
7   g      P     X    A2         7
8   h      P     Y    A2         1
9   i      P     Y    A2         2
10  j      P     Y    A2         3
11  a      M     X    A1         1
12  b      M     X    A1         2
13  c      M     X    A1         3
14  d      M     X    A1         4
15  e      M     X    A1         5
16  f      M     X    A2         6
17  g      M     X    A2         7
18  h      M     Y    A2         1
19  i      M     Y    A2         2
20  j      M     Y    A2         3
```

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150968/adding-an-repeated-index-for-factors/6151333#6151333 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162685/how-can-i-rank-observations-in-group-faster http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848362/adding-a-counter-column-for-a-set-of-similar-rows-in-r

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the `dplyr` package as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
df = df %>%
  group_by(group, sub.id) %>%
  mutate(replicate=1:length(id))

> df
Source: local data frame [20 x 5]
Groups: group, sub.id

   id sub.id group class replicate
1   a      P     X    A1         1
2   b      P     X    A1         2
3   c      P     X    A1         3
4   d      P     X    A1         4
5   e      P     X    A1         5
6   f      P     X    A2         6
7   g      P     X    A2         7
8   h      P     Y    A2         1
9   i      P     Y    A2         2
10  j      P     Y    A2         3
11  a      M     X    A1         1
12  b      M     X    A1         2
13  c      M     X    A1         3
14  d      M     X    A1         4
15  e      M     X    A1         5
16  f      M     X    A2         6
17  g      M     X    A2         7
18  h      M     Y    A2         1
19  i      M     Y    A2         2
20  j      M     Y    A2         3
```

`dplyr` also has the built-in function `n()`, which you can use instead of `length()` as follows:

```
df = df %>%
  group_by(group, sub.id) %>%
  mutate(replicate=1:n())
```

`n()` automatically counts the number of rows in each combination of the grouping variables (in this case `group` and `sub.id`).

In your example data frame, `id` was already in alphabetical order. If this isn't the case and if it's important to have the numerical order of `replicate` correspond to the alphabetical order of `id`, then you can sort the data frame first, using the `arrange` function. In the example below, the data frame is sorted first by `group`, then by `sub.id`, then by `id`:

```
df = df %>%
  arrange(group, sub.id, id) %>%
  group_by(group, sub.id) %>%
  mutate(replicate=1:n())
```