# Count the number previous items in by group in R

Tags: r, counting

I would like to create a new variable which counts the number of previous items in a by group. Here is what I mean, taking the `esoph` dataset as an example.

first I sort the dataset by my by group `esoph$agegp, esoph$alcgp` and an additional value column `-esoph$ncontrols`.

This gives me the following dataset

```
x<-esoph[order(esoph$agegp, esoph$alcgp, -esoph$ncontrols ), ]
x

   agegp     alcgp    tobgp ncases ncontrols
1  25-34 0-39g/day 0-9g/day      0        40
2  25-34 0-39g/day    10-19      0        10
3  25-34 0-39g/day    20-29      0         6
4  25-34 0-39g/day      30+      0         5
5  25-34     40-79 0-9g/day      0        27
6  25-34     40-79    10-19      0         7
8  25-34     40-79      30+      0         7
7  25-34     40-79    20-29      0         4
9  25-34    80-119 0-9g/day      0         2
11 25-34    80-119      30+      0         2
...
```

Now, I would like to create a new variable with some sort of index, increasing by one on every row. Whenever the next by group starts, the index goes back to 1.

The resulting table would be the following (with the additional index column):

```
   agegp     alcgp    tobgp ncases ncontrols index
1  25-34 0-39g/day 0-9g/day      0        40     1
2  25-34 0-39g/day    10-19      0        10     2
3  25-34 0-39g/day    20-29      0         6     3
4  25-34 0-39g/day      30+      0         5     4
5  25-34     40-79 0-9g/day      0        27     1
6  25-34     40-79    10-19      0         7     2
8  25-34     40-79      30+      0         7     3
7  25-34     40-79    20-29      0         4     4
9  25-34    80-119 0-9g/day      0         2     1
11 25-34    80-119      30+      0         2     2
...
```

How do I calculate this column?

Thanks!

Comment: Some type of a dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162685/how-can-i-rank-observations-in-group-faster) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848362/adding-a-counter-column-for-a-set-of-similar-rows-in-r) and about 1MM similar questions

Comment: @DavidArenburg In the first one, it is `rank` in the column title and in the second it is `counter` instead of `count` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be approached using either specialized packages such as `dplyr` which has `row_number()`.  We need to group by the variable ('alcgp') and create a new column using `mutate`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by( alcgp) %>%
   mutate(indx= row_number())
```

Or using `ave` from `base R`.  We group by 'alcgp' and in the `FUN` we can specify `seq_along`.  I used `seq_along(alcgp)` as it may not work if the variable is `factor` class.

```
 df1$indx <- with(df1, ave(seq_along(alcgp), alcgp, FUN=seq_along))
```

Another convenient function in `splitstackshape` i.e. `getanID`

```
 library(splitstackshape)
 getanID(df1, 'alcgp')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `data.table` solution:

```
R> (data.table(Data)[,index := 1:.N, by = "agegp,alcgp"])
    agegp     alcgp    tobgp ncases ncontrols index
 1: 25-34 0-39g/day 0-9g/day      0        40     1
 2: 25-34 0-39g/day    10-19      0        10     2
 3: 25-34 0-39g/day    20-29      0         6     3
 4: 25-34 0-39g/day      30+      0         5     4
 5: 25-34     40-79 0-9g/day      0        27     1
 6: 25-34     40-79    10-19      0         7     2
 7: 25-34     40-79      30+      0         7     3
 8: 25-34     40-79    20-29      0         4     4
 9: 25-34    80-119 0-9g/day      0         2     1
10: 25-34    80-119      30+      0         2     2
```

---

```
library(data.table)
##
Data <- read.table(
  text = "   agegp     alcgp    tobgp ncases ncontrols
1  25-34 0-39g/day 0-9g/day      0        40
2  25-34 0-39g/day    10-19      0        10
3  25-34 0-39g/day    20-29      0         6
4  25-34 0-39g/day      30+      0         5
5  25-34     40-79 0-9g/day      0        27
6  25-34     40-79    10-19      0         7
8  25-34     40-79      30+      0         7
7  25-34     40-79    20-29      0         4
9  25-34    80-119 0-9g/day      0         2
11 25-34    80-119      30+      0         2",
  header = TRUE,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```